# NSNumber gives wrong int value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, nsnumber

I have a program that gets cookies. One param of this cookie is an NSNumber. So I save it to database as

```
sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, HEREisNSNUMBER);
```

Saving this value as:

```
cookieObj.created = [paramsDictionary valueForKey:@"Created"];
```

then I create and object of class, and get this parameter into NSNumber; after that, I have a wrong value. For example: In cookie I have a `329822675` after saving this changes to `79931776`. How can I correctly save that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, [HEREisNSNUMBER intValue]);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but now I have `0` value. What can it be??

Comment: can you log the NSNumber `NSLog(@"%@", HEREisNSNUMBER)`

Comment: @mazder: your probably getting the wrong column (change 2 in something else)

Comment: I Did it! =) Thanks to all. Just changed NSNumber* to int and send value as `[HEREisNSNUMBER intValue]`, after that value returns right =)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the int-value of an NSNumber. That's where it goes wrong.

Use this instead:
`sqlite3_bind_int  (addStmt, 2, [HEREisNSNUMBER intValue]);`
`

Answer (score 0):

*NSNumber* is a reference type. You should not assign it as a *int* value directly. You should get the `intValue` of *NSNumber* and bind it to sqlite3 statement.

```
sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, [HEREisNSNUMBER intValue]);
```